# MessageBox duplicates when i use foreach statement c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, forms, foreach

I'm having a little trouble. When a user logs in, if the manager has set a reminder it will come up when the user logs in. Problem is, when I use the foreach statement it works when there's 1 reminder but if the manager has set 2 reminders the message box (containing the reminder) duplicates the first reminder and doesn't show the second reminder.

code:

```
    private void getreminder()
    {
        EmployeeReminderDE db2 = new EmployeeReminderDE();
        System.Windows.Forms.Form f = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["LoginScreen"];
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(((LoginScreen)f).idTb.Text);
        var getReminder = db2.Reminders.Where(a => a.Id == id).ToList();

        foreach (var reminder in getReminder)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(reminder.ReminderDetails, "Reminder from manager", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be grateful, thanks! - Richard

[image: Datbase]

[image: reminder 1]reminder #2 (should say reminder #2)[image: Reminder 2]

Comment: Are you sure the second reminder isn't the same message as the first reminder?  The if condition isn't necessary since if the count was zero, the MessageBox line wouldn't be reached anyway.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense anyway. The if statement within the loop will never execute if `getReminder.Count == 0`, as then the loop will never be entered.

Comment: When displaying your message box, you use `reminder.Reminder1` -- what is the schema of the Reminders table?

Comment: MessageBox is a lousy debugging tool except for the most trivial of things.  Your schema looks like Reminder, but your property is Reminder1.  Where is this code running?  In a different thread?

Comment: Did you actually debug and inspect/verify that `getReminder` actually contains what you think it should? I suspect that you have wrong data in there already. Otherwise what you say is not really possible with your code.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `foreach` line and see what are the contents of `getReminder`. If it contains two entries with the same text, there's something wrong somewhere else. Your code looks ok to me (*ok as in -it should do what you expect-, it definitely doesn't look all that great*)

Comment: The column is called reminder1 in the database (Doesn't have anything to do with the code).

Comment: @RichardJacobs do you have any distinct key in the database for your reminders? (one different key per row, not the `Id` you are using to differentiate the user)

Comment: The screen shot of your data table looks like Reminder, without a 1 on the end.  Again though, where is this code running?  Why do you have to find the form through the OpenForms collection?

Comment: I think VS automatically renamed the Reminder property to Reminder1 due to some name conflict. I suggest to change column name to `ReminderDetails` (or something) and refresh the schema.

Comment: Cut off getReminder.Count > 0, as it does not make sense. Than, check the type of Reminder1 property - it looks like a navigation property, rather than an actual property. If it is a navigation property, then you see its ToString() value.

Comment: @Alexei nope, `MessageBox.Show` accepts `string` as its first parameter. If it's a navigation property, it would never (or, not unless you have explicitly created the type implicit conversion, and I doubt it for this case) be implicitly converted to string by itself (you'd need a `string.Format` or a `+` concatenation or something of the sort)

Comment: @RichardJacobs did you actually try to debug and see the contents of `getReminder` before iterating it? If it shows two rows with the same content, then there's something wrong somewhere else, and we can't help if we don't see the rest

Comment: Why do you have two rows with the same id? Have you flagged this property as a primary key in the entity model perhaps?

Comment: If it was the PK he wouldn't be getting two rows but one.

Answer (score -1):

There should be 2 message boxes. Just check if they are not overlapping.

Comment: There is 2 message boxes but they both contain reminder number 1 and not number 1 and 2

Comment: Impossible. Message boxes are modal. The second one will only be shown after the first one was closed. Two overlapping message boxes indicate a threading problem.

Comment: In both the cases why is the Id same?

Comment: @Nikita looks like `Id` identifies the user, not the row

Comment: after it display's the first messagebox, does it go 2nd time in the loop?

Comment: First, this is not an answer to the problem, you could have commented. Second as @ThorstenDittmar said modal dialogs never overlap on same thread.

Comment: Yes the Id identifies the user. I don't understand why its duplicating the first reminder and not showing the second reminder. I hope I can get around this. Thanks for commenting guys.

Comment: @Marshal I cannot comment on the same thread as it's minimum eligibility is 50 points.

Comment: Yes Nikita it does. It's strange.

Comment: @Nikita Still you cannot post comments as answers. [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)